# ATTENDEE "RESPONDED-AT" parameter in iCal

Tags: datetime, outlook, icalendar, appointment

Is it possible to have somewhat like this in iCal?

ATTENDEE:RESPONDED-AT:20120728T050000Z:MAILTO:test@domain.com

The iCal spec does not seem to provide any means for tracking attendee response's datetime. However, when syncing with MS Outlook, it becomes a problem because Outlook will display you "Please respond" until you set its AppointmentItem.ReplyTime properly (in case if you're an attendee to event). Of course, I can set this to some arbitrary value (like the moment of creating the event), but it won't be too friendly to end users when they see this in user interface of Outlook.

Currently I'm trying to add RESPONDED-AT manually but I'm not sure other CalDAV/iCal clients won't clear it as it's non-standard.